# Как установить Angular Universal?

Tags: angular2, установка

Добрый день!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в том, как правильно установить Angular Universal.

Казалось бы, что может быть понятнее и проще. Зайти на официальный сайт, пройти ясно и чётко описанные шаги. Если что-то пошло не так, то в Гугле всегда должна найтись нужная информация.

Я сейчас хочу перевести один из своих сайтов, написанный на Angular JS, на Angular Universal для того, чтобы обеспечить серверный рендеринг и помочь поисковикам индексировать информацию на сайте.

С чем я столкнулся и что я уже проделал сейчас. Для начала я зашёл на официальный сайт Angular Universal и прошёл те шаги, которые там описаны. Установил Node.js последнюю версию, записал пути в $PATH, развернул в PhpStorm проект, который указан на Git.
При попытке выполнить команды

> npm install body-parser angular2-universal preboot express --save
>
> typings install node express body-parser serve-static express-serve-static-core mime --ambient

получил предупреждения и ошибки.

Добавил файл server.js, который представлен на официальном сайте. При попытке запустить команду node server.js появляются ошибки, связанные с командами import в server.js.

Хорошо. Пошёл на Гугл. Нашёл несколько других описаний как развернуть Angular. Один проект даже запустился, однако без файла server.js - а он, насколько я понимаю, важен для серверного рендеринга.

При попытках установить Angular CLI тоже появляются ошибки.

В итоге, я вижу, что даже просто установить Angular Universal оказалось не легко. Инструкции часто датируются началом или серединой 2016 года и видимо устарели.

Я буду благодарен за помощь и совет. Было бы хорошо получить ответ в виде пунктов, что и как нужно делать, по шагам, какие команды выполнять, как правильно подключить server.js и обеспечить серверный рендеринг.

Если найдётся грамотный ответ, я уверен, он поможет многим другим людям в решении такой же задачи, поскольку в Гугл люди часто пишут о том, что сталкиваются с ошибками при установке Angular Universal. Кроме того, почти всё, что касается этой темы - на английском языке. На русском я пока не встречал подробные обсуждения такой темы. Тем более, хороший совет здесь будет очень ценен.

Comment: Как добавить серверный рендеринг:

На этом ресурсе хорошо описано на английском: https://scotch.io/tutorials/server-side-rendering-in-angular-2-with-angular-universal

1. Скачиваем начальный проект с файлами для серверного рендеринга по ссылке https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.
2. Устанавливаем в папку проекта npm.
3. Запускаем > npm start. Идем на localhost:3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Добавление в процессе поисков:**
разобрался как правильно установить Angular 2, пока без серверного рендеринга. Это актуально на дату 19.02.17.

1. Загрузить и установить последнюю версию Node.js с официального сайта по ссылке https://nodejs.org
2. Скачать начальный проект, указанный на официальном сайте Angular Universal по ссылке https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter
3. В директории проекта запустить команду для инсталляции npm, с помощью терминала или из вашей IDE. 
   Поскольку я работаю на Mac, то команда будет иметь вид:

   > sudo npm install

Важно использовать sudo (с использованием пароля, иначе может возникнуть ошибка доступа). Для Windows - нужно предпринять аналогичные по смыслу действия.

Если вы ставили npm раньше, то лучше обновить версию, убрать папку node_modules и инсталлировать заново. Это можно сделать командами для Mac:

> sudo npm install -g npm@latest
>   sudo rm -rf node_modules
>   sudo npm install

В итоге в папке вашего проекта появится папка node_modules.

4. Выполняете команду

   > npm start

После выполнения команды в браузере набираете **localhost:3000** и видите свой начальный проект на Angular 2.

В будущем вам понадобится **команда остановки сервера** из терминала: Ctrl+C

В этом проекте не используется серверный рендеринг. Если кто-то знает, как добавить это в проект - буду благодарен за совет.

**Добавление**: Итак, разобрался как добавить серверный рендеринг.

На этом ресурсе хорошо описано на английском: https://scotch.io/tutorials/server-side-rendering-in-angular-2-with-angular-universal

1. Скачиваем начальный проект с файлами для серверного рендеринга  по ссылке https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.
2. Устанавливаем в папку проекта npm.
3. Запускаем > npm start. Идем на localhost:3000.

При просмотре html-кода видно, что рендерится только страница Home, все данные с сервера в ней отображаются корректно. 
Свои страницы добавляйте по аналогии с Home.

Помните, что роуты и свои компоненты нужно добавлять в том числе в файлы app.module.ts, server.routes.ts.