# Можно ли индексировать веб-приложение на Angular 2 поисковыми ботами?

Tags: angularjs, seo, angular2, индексация

Здравствуйте.

У меня сейчас возникла проблема — разрабатывая сайт на первом ангуляре, я абсолютно забыл (или не знал), что такое приложение не будет индексироваться поисковыми роботами. Я перечитал/ пересмотрел кучу туторов по теме SEO для js-сайтов, и понял что такие сайты должны рендерить страницу и отправлять ее боту поисковику, а пользователь получает обычную динамическую страницу как и раньше.

Вопрос мой к знатокам — что будет лучше, в какую сторону смотреть:

```
// ставить prerender на первый angular и работать с ним

// начать уже наконец изучать angular2 (он вроде как более дружелюбен с SEO, так как рендерит страницу по дефолту, поправьте если не так понял)

// прибегать к помощи php фреймворков?
```

Сейчас сайт держится на первом Angular, и как бы это просто проект ради хобби /в свободное от основной работы время/, и для подтягивания JS. Благодарю за советы

Comment: Моё мнение: Angular2 - это тупик. Не уверен, что есть смысл вообще с ним связываться. Попробуй реакт.

Comment: AngulsrJS (первый) поисковиками индексируется, если правильно сделать. Его собственная документация написана на нём и индексируется.

Comment: @Qwertiy а реакт-то индексируется?)

Comment: @andreymal, если правильно сделать, то индексируется что угодно. К тому же у реакта есть серверный рендеринг, если что. У второго ангуляра как бы тоже есть, но насколько он там реально работает, не знаю.

Comment: я react хочу после изучить, мне для работы сейчас требуется angular/angular2 ionic/ ionic2 соответственно. слышал про реакт, что это сильнейшая штука, но пока что мне рано) думаю после angular2 мне будет проще начинать изучение реакта

Comment: вообщем во втором ангуляре есть англяр универсал https://universal.angular.io/ (грубо говоря создаёт копию страницы на сервере), но работает он через nodejs. Тоесть если сайт написан на php он не подойдёт. Индексация на ангуляре достаточно сложная штука. Допустим гугл добавил для первого и второго  англяра гугл аналитик https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2. Но насколько хорошо он индексирует я не знаю

Answer (score -1):

Angular 2 **не имеет** поддержки серверного рендеринга и приложения, написанные на нем, не индексируется поисковиками.

Для индексации приложения поисковиками создана версия **Angular Universal**. В неё включена поддержка серверного рендеринга и, соответственно, индексация будет происходить.

Для того, чтобы посмотреть небольшое описание и запустить маленький тестовый пример на Angular Universal - см. описание по шагам:
[Как установить Angular Universal?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629415/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-angular-universal/632785)

Нужно также учесть, что серверный рендеринг в Angular Universal на текущий момент осуществляется с помощью Node.js.